# Unable to skip stage inside stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've a stage which is inside a stage and I want to skip it based on condition in `when` -

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Dynamic stages") {
            steps {
                script {
                    serverAStatus = false
                    def tests = CLIENTS.split(',')
                    def builders = [:]
                    for (test in tests) {
                        def test1 = test
                        builders[test] = {

                            stage("Test ${test1}") {
                                 when {
                                expression {
                                    (serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ")))

                                }
                            }
                                node('master') {
                                    script {
                                        echo "Executing stage ${test1}"
                                        echo "Client is " + test1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives error - `No such DSL method when inside steps`

Instead of `when`, I tried to use if statement inside stage like -

```
if ((!serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ")))) {
      echo "******************************************************"
      Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
}
```

but this does not skip stage.

Please help me how can I skip stage in my scenario where I've stage inside stage.

Comment: `steps` are inside of `stages`, and not the other way around. Make that fix and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Matt OP is using a script step which actually can have a stage sub section.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ? If so What was the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

First, to clear some misunderstandings, it is actually valid to define a `stage` inside of a `script` step. This is a common pattern to dynamically add stages to a declarative pipeline.

Within a `script` step, the rules for scripted pipeline apply. Scripted pipeline has a `stage` function, which doesn't require `steps` or even `script` children. Everything within a scripted `stage` also uses scripted syntax.

You can skip a scripted stage simply by using a Groovy `if` statement:

```groovy
script {
    if( serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ")) ) {
        stage('A Stage') {
            echo 'Hello'
        }
    }
}
```

This has the drawback that the stage will be completely **missing** from the Blue Ocean pipeline view.

What we actually want is to show the stage, but in the **skipped** state, as we are used from declarative pipeline. This can be achieved using the [imperative when step](https://github.com/comquent/imperative-when) (related [blog post](https://comquent.de/en/skipped-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/)).

The result is not perfect, as Blue Ocean will draw a straight line through the stage (instead of curved line around the stage), but the stage button represents the skipped state.

After including the shared library as described by the [blog post](https://comquent.de/en/skipped-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/), we can now write:

```groovy
script {
    stage("Test ${test1}") {
        when( serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ")) ) {
            echo 'Hello'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your complete sample rewritten using "imperative when" and removed some obsolete code:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Dynamic stages") {
            steps {
                script {
                    serverAStatus = false
                    def tests = CLIENTS.split(',')
                    def builders = [:]
                    for (test in tests) {
                        def test1 = test
                        builders[test] = {

                            stage("Test ${test1}") {
                                when( serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ")) ) {
                                    node('master') {
                                        echo "Executing stage ${test1}"
                                        echo "Client is " + test1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of the sample, the `node('master')` could also be removed. I left it in, because you propably want to run the parallel stages on multiple nodes in parallel. In this case you would replace 'master' with a common node label or pass explicit node names depending on variable `test1`.

Comment: Wow @zett42, this is so awesome that I'm going to steal this immediately.

Comment: @MaratC Feel free 

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you program a *scripted pipeline* inside your *declarative pipeline*. Their syntax is a bit different, and `when` constraint is only for declarative ones.

Try writing this in scripted:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Dynamic stages") {
            steps {
                script { // inside this block, scripted pipeline syntax only
                    serverAStatus = false // note that no tests will run
                    def tests = CLIENTS.split(',')
                    def builders = [:]
                    for (test in tests) {
                        def test1 = test
                        if (serverAStatus && (test1.equals("ABC") || test1.equals("XYZ"))) {
                            builders[test1] = {
                                node('master') {
                                    script {
                                        echo "Executing stage ${test1}"
                                        echo "Client is " + test1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```