# When statement inside function called by Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to use a `when` statement inside of a function in a jenkinsfile?

My issue is the following: I created a deployment script using `parallel` that will perform it using a list of servers that are pre-configured (simple array) where I iterate over them to do the job. There is a parameter that is set when starting the build that will define which servers it should update, and here is the issue. I can add an `if` statement and it will work but, when checking blue ocean, all of the servers are green with 30ms, meaning that it didnt update as I wanted, not white as it was skipped when using `when` function.

Example below

```
def deployEnvironment(env) {
  defineEnvironment()
  defineAgent('build')
  deploy(env)
}
```

If I try adding a `when` statement I get the message saying that the `when` statement is not within the steps accepted commands, even if I add it outside of the steps (or anywhere)

```
  when {
    expression { (someValidation())}
  }
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to skip stage inside stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928388/unable-to-skip-stage-inside-stage)

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939531/7571258

Comment: I came across both examples but I was trying to avoid the if condition before the stage itself since they are done programaatically. I opted to do with `if` statement for now and only the server that I want will be displayed. Ideally would be all with the blank ball that they were not executed. Anyway, thank @zett42

Comment: Well, you could still define an empty stage to be able to mark it as "skipped": `stage('StageName') { when( $false ) {} }`

Comment: You can call the `Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)` inside your stage and it will mark it as Skipped as you want. (notice you will need to import `org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils`)